# Angular Reload page ngSubmit

Tags: angular, typescript

When I submit the form the first time

[image]

But When I submit the form again, it changes the url but does not update the page

[image]

app.component.ts

```
 searchString: String;

 constructor(private router: Router){}

      handleSearch(){    
        this.router.navigateByUrl(`/search?q=${this.searchString}`);
          }
```

app.component.html

```
 <form (ngSubmit)='handleSearch()'><input matInput type="text" name="searchString" [(ngModel)]='searchString'></form>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
  {path: "search", component: SearchResultComponent},
```

search-result.component.ts

```
export class SearchResultComponent implements OnInit {
  results:any;
  searchQuery:any;

  private routeSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private music: MusicDataService,private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.routeSub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params =>{
      this.searchQuery = params['q'] || 0;
    })

    this.music.searchArtists(this.searchQuery).subscribe(
      data =>{
        this.results = data.artists.items.filter(item => item.images.length > 0);
        console.log(this.results);
        
      }
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => {
      return false;
    };
    
  }
```

seemed to solve my issue in the app.component.ts
Would like to know how it works though?